# plotly.js: How To Plot 100 points In One Second

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly.js

So what I am trying to accomplish is to plot over 100 points in one second. I am using `plotlyJs` right now.

But it looks quite slow when it comes to plotting. I set the time to `10` so that 100 points can be plotted in one second. But as I can see the Chart is working quite slow its plotting less amount of points in one second time.

Here is the code that I am trying:

**The Code:**

```
<script>
    function getData() {
        console.log(Math.random());
        return Math.random();
    }  
    Plotly.plot('chart',[{
        y:[getData()],
        type:'line'
    }]);

    var cnt = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        Plotly.extendTraces('chart',{ y:[[getData()]]}, [0]);
        cnt++;
        if(cnt > 1000) {
            Plotly.relayout('chart',{
                xaxis: {
                    range: [cnt-1000,cnt]
                }
            });
        }
    },10);
</script>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/qme9wL2u/) is the **fiddle** that I created.

Please tell me If I am missing something or this not possible in `plotlyjs`?
The problem only arises of plotting over 100 points in one second.

If it's not possible in `PlotlyJs` I am open for any other charting Library suggestion.

Comment: set interval to even lower value. You can go less than 1 too, eg. `0.5`

Comment: It doesn't matter. that Chart's speed appears to be same. @VaibhavVishala

Comment: For me, it was faster.

Comment: The timer will round values under 5ms up to 5ms. There is no sense in decreasing below that.

Answer (score 3):

Your eye can only see changes at < 60fps, and the monitors therefore only rerender at 60fps. That's every *16ms*. It doesn't make sense to run a timer in a smaller interval, as you won't see the updates at that speed anyway. Instead, slow down the interval, and show multiple points at a time. That's faster, and the speed in which the plot is shown can be adjusted more easily.

Comment: your Suggestion is understandable. But the problem is that I have to show the points one by one for live streaming, and the data will come at the speed of more than 100 samples per second. I have to make the stream look smoother . and don't want to show multiple data points to be displayed at once

Comment: It won't show any "smoother". Wether you render 1 point at 5ms or 3 at 15ns doesn't matter.